# Can ADB recognize a device on bootloop (soft-brick)?

Tags: android, mtp, adb

I own a Samsung tablet (GT-n5110) and it is in **bootloop**.
I don't have a data backup (yes, I'm an idiot). It isn't totally bricked, so I can access recovery mode (HOME+VOLUM UP+POWER), but before wiping it to factory configuration I am desperatelly trying to back it up. **It isn't rooted**.

I'm new at Linux, but I use it as my only OS. I've read in many foruns that it is possible to back up an android device through ADB tools in linux, but **my device isn't recognized with
`$ sudo adb devices`**

I have **alredy updated UDEV rules** with the correct idVendor and idProduct and I have alredy **reinitiated ADB server**.

When I connect the device to the computer, it recognizes the tablet but says it **cannot access it due to a MTP problem** (this happened alredy before the bootloop, but it didn't bother me as I didn't use the computer to back the device up as I should have done). **I have alredy installed and updated mtp-tools**.

Is there a way for ADB to recognize and access this device? **Should I keep looking?** Or is it simply impossible for a bootlooping device to be recognized though ADB or any other tools?

Thanks A LOT, I really need this help!

Comment: It depends on what stage the tablet gets to before it reboots. If ADB can't connect to it, I don't think anything else can. You should probably go to [android.se] and ask how to get the device out of a bootloop, if possible.

Comment: I'm gonna try it. If anyone has the same doubt, I also found info about adb_usb.ini. It didn't work for me either, but it seems to help in many cases.  I'm gonna try updating adb, as the newer version seems not to be the one on the repository.

Comment: What makes me crazy (as far as Ubuntu, not Android goes) is that I can see the device through various commands in terminal. So it seems to be it should be accessible someway....

Comment: Again, you'll have to ask that on Android.se. This isn't our area of expertise.

Answer (score 0):

I've been there too (on my BQ Aquaris M10): [Aquaris M10 FHD tablet stuck in boot loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/837728/aquaris-m10-fhd-tablet-stuck-in-boot-loop)

I confirm that I couldn't access the tablet neither with adb nor phablet-shell.

However -see my post- once I got into the recovery mode, a simple "wipe cache" was enough to solve the problem, so a full factory reset was not necessary.

This might help you on a next occasion - or others suffering from the same.